# UNION ALL with different number of columns and creating Nulls MySQL

Tags: mysql, union, historical-db

I am trying to create a query that will UNION ALL a set of historical data and a set of new data that have a different number of columns. I want it to UNION ALL on all matching columns and create a new column in the historical data set as NULL if the new data has a new column.

Here is my current code I know is wrong:

```
SELECT * FROM `historical_data`

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM `new_data`
```

Comment: You have to make both SELECTs have the same number of column, so add empty ones with ''  in the column positions, that are not existent..

Comment: No asterisks, separate fields names only.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without manually adding new columns every time?

Comment: No way. All separate queries in UNION must have the same fields amount in output, and fieldtypes must match too positionally.

Answer (score 1):

For example, if fields 1 and 4 are present in both tables, and fields 2 and 3 in new table only:

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3, field4 FROM `new_data`
UNION ALL
SELECT field1,  NULL ,  NULL , field4 FROM `historical_data`
```